# Call function from external .js file

Tags: prototypejs

I have a draw.js file with me which has a function as

```
var drawArrow=function(x1,y1,x2,y2)
{ 
// some code 
}
```

In my html page in head I wrote

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="draw.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function callme() {
  // insert code here
  }
</script>
```

Please tell me waht code do I need to write in **callme()** to call **drawArrow** function of **draw.js**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is external when you call js file all methods are easily accessible as it is create on same page now simply do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function callme() {
drawArrow=function(x1,y1,x2,y2);
  // insert code here
  }
</script>
```

Comment: so the function written in draw.js file will get called and also it will return a variable named drawArrow. am I right?

Comment: I call the drawArrow Function directly in my callme(): `drawArrow(x1,y1,x2,y2);` it worked.